# Unity: Changing the color of object with input and using OnCollisionEnter to check if it's same color with other object

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, collision

I want to change color of player when user press J,K,L /and colors red, green, blue as you can see in the code below. 
It works well. When player hit the ground, it has to be same color with the ground.
If it is not level will start again.
With my code i can do that too.
The problem is when the player hit the ground with the same color and when the player still on the same ground, if i change the color of player, it is not starting the level again.
I tried raycast but it didnt worked well.
I know i'm making a logic mistake somewhere but cant find it.
Here my codes;

-Player Code-

```
var player : Transform;


function Update () {


    //Check if J key Down if it is change player name and color    
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.J))

        {

            player.name = "red";
            player.gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.red;

        }

        //Check if K key Down if it is change player name and color    
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.K))
            {
                player.name = "green";
                player.gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.green;
            }

            //Check if L key Down if it is change player name and color    
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.L))
                {
                    player.name = "blue";
                    player.gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.blue;
                }

}
```

-Ground Code-

```
//Prefabs    
var player : Transform;    
var redLand : Transform;    
var greenLand : Transform;    
var blueLand : Transform;

//Assigning prefabs on editor    
public var isRedLand = false;
public var isGreenLand = false;
public var isBlueLand = false;


private var isColorRed = false;
private var isColorGreen = false;
private var isColorBlue = false;



function OnCollisionEnter () {  
ColorChange();

}

function ColorChange () 
{    
//Check if the isRedLand true and isGreenLand and isBlueLand false     
if (isRedLand && !isGreenLand && !isBlueLand)
{
    //Check if player name red if it is change the tag of it    
    if(player.name == "red")
        {   

            isColorRed = true;

        //if it is not red restart level    
        }else       
            {
                Application.LoadLevel ("1");
                isColorRed = false;
            }
}

//Check if the isGreenLand true and isRedLand and isBlueLand false 

if(isGreenLand && !isRedLand && !isBlueLand)
{
    //Check if player name red if it is change the tag of it                
    if(player.name == "green")
        {               

            isColorRed = true;      

        //if it is not red restart level            
        }else               
            {
            Application.LoadLevel ("1");
            isColorGreen = false;
            }
}

//Check if the isBlueLand true and isRedLand and isGreenLand false     
if(isBlueLand && !isGreenLand && !isRedLand)

{
    //Check if player name red if it is change the tag of it        
    if(player.name == "blue")
        {                       

            isColorBlue = true; 

        //if it is not red restart level                    
        }else                       
            {
                Application.LoadLevel ("1");
                isColorBlue = false;
            }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question right the code should be fine if you change

```
function OnCollisionEnter () {  
ColorChange();

}
```

to

```
function OnCollisionStay () {  
    ColorChange();
}
```

`OnCollisionEnter` is called only when collision starts. `OnCollisionStay` is called on every frame while colliders are touching.